# Why does toggling image with angular variable on hover cause the image to shift downward

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Consider this [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZILFkaYtm2tuR6vwwCQc?p=preview)

We can observe that if we hover on to the tiles (which is control by `ng-if`) the tiles get shift vertically.

Here is the css

```
.tile-wrapper {
    width: 142px;
    height: 142px;
    border: solid 1px #cecece;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I verify that if I got rid of everything except

```
.tile-wrapper {
    width: 142px;
    height: 142px;
    border: solid 1px #cecece;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The same phenonmenon still happen

I am not exactly sure what is the problem.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a `vertical-align: middle` to `.wrapper` fixes the issue. It is **caused by the `display: inline-block`** rule. So always don't forget to add `vertical-align` to `inline-block` items.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: Preview]

**Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/zRZ8rVo0zSJeVYxx57Rm?p=preview**